# toggle specific class on specific element - Polymer

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

I have a series of `paper-input` elements each with an `iron-icon` that is initially hidden until text is input etc.

```
<paper-input id="one" class="one" on-input="doFunction">
    <iron-icon suffix icon="clear" id="clearOne" class="clear"></iron-icon>
</paper-input>
<paper-input id="two" class="two" on-input="doFunction">
    <iron-icon suffix icon="clear" id="clearTwo" class="clear"></iron-icon>
</paper-input>
```

Is there any way of using JS such that I can make this happen?

I currently have the following JS:

```
doFunction : function(e) {
    if (e.currentTarget.value != '') {
        /* toggle the clear icon for that input only */
    } else {
        /* toggle the clear icon for that input only again */
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way!

```
doFunction : function(e) {
    if (e.currentTarget.value != '') {
        Polymer.dom(e.currentTarget).querySelector('iron-icon').classList.remove('clear')
    } else {
        Polymer.dom(e.currentTarget).querySelector('iron-icon').classList.add('clear')
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed Pascal. I forgot to mention that I was animating the 'clear' icons to slide in, as I mentioned to Tony above, do I altered your code a little to add and remove another CSS class rather than you had, removing and adding the actual icon class. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

You could alternatively accomplish this with CSS (and no JavaScript), using an `<iron-icon>.hidden` attribute that is automatically set to `true` only when the `<paper-input>.value` property is empty:

```
<paper-input value="{{value1}}">
  <iron-icon hidden$="[[!value1]]"></iron-icon>
</paper-input>
```

Make sure to initialize the bound property so that the `<iron-icon>.hidden` attribute's binding is evaluated upon attachment:

```
Polymer({
  // ...
  properties: {
    value1: {
      type: String,
      value: ''  // initialize for data binding
    }
  }
});
```

[Polymer 1 demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/MvbzRP?editors=1010)

[Polymer 2 demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/brBQZo?editors=1010)

Comment: Thanks for the input Tony. I was thinking of using the JS way as I'm wanting to have the 'clear' icon slide in with a transition rather than just appear.

Comment: Ok. That could also be done using CSS and attribute binding, but whatever works best for you. :-)